# how to search inside of pdf files in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search

I want to search inside of pdf files in sharepoint 2013. How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing PDF files is OOTB funcationality in the SharePoint 2013, You need to run the full crawl.

> Sharepoint 2013 can only index PDF files with text layers, so files
>   without one will not be indexed.